# Django, How to update DateTimeField attribute only when one specific attribute is changed

Tags: python, django, save

I would like to update the attribute `date_assigned` only when the attribute `Customer` is changed. I know that I have to overwrite the save function within the same model but i don't know exactly how.

```
class Ip(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol="IPv4", null=False, unique=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,)
    date_assigned = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) on overriding the save method.

One very useful tool for this is in the [model_utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html?highlight=fieldtracker#fieldtracker-implementation-details) package.

```
from model_utils import FieldTracker

class Ip(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol="IPv4", null=False, unique=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,)
    date_assigned = models.DateTimeField()

    customer_tracker = FieldTracker(fields=['customer'])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.customer_tracker.changed():
            self.date_assigned = timezone.now()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Exactly, this is what I was looking for, and then i would delete auto_now=True from the DateTimeField.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to remove the auto_now flag.